# Does Goryaev's chamber have the same grid layout as the conventional counting chamber used in the West?

Tags: hematology, terminology

I'm translating a Russian biotec text where some cell counting operations are mentioned. The piece of equipment the authors mention in this context is "Goryaev's chamber" (камера Горяева):

> We discarded the supernatant, washed the cells with DPBS twice (suspended and centrifuged them for 10 min at 200 g), then diluted with 10 ml of ADCC assay medium and assessed the concentration and viability of the cells in a **Goryaev's chamber**.

Is a Goryaev's chamber any different in terms of its counting grid layout from the [conventional hemocytometer chamber described in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemocytometer)?

I would like to translate the phrase simply as "using a cell counting chamber" or "using a hemocytometer". The Multitran dictionary [does offer these words](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%EA%E0%EC%E5%F0%E0%20%E3%EE%F0%FF%E5%E2%E0) as possible translations, but it occurred to me that Goryaev's chamber might differ somewhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description at http://cldtest.ru/hdbk/chamber

It appears to be functionally the same device, except the only the smallest square are marked (0.25 nL and 4 nL), and the total capacity is 90 nL instead of 100 nL. A hemocytometer could be used in place of a Goryaev's chamber (though not necessarily the reverse).

Comment: Welcome to the site, Eliane!